# Click differences between text box and a button

Tags: vb.net, winforms

On a form where I display data, if the user clicks the text box I open a virtual keyboard (form) and allow them to click buttons to enter data. When this virtual keyboard is opened, if the path to open was from clicking a text box, the first click in the new form (virtual keyboard) is ignored. If the virtual keyboard form is opened from clicking a button (from the first form), it works fine. I can't find a difference between triggering the virtual keyboard form from either control.

Comment: Tags: `[events]`, `[button]`, `[textbox]`, `[click]`. EPIC. Close-voting.

Comment: *Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.*

Comment: Specifically, when I open a form and the user is to click on buttons to fill a text box (these buttons add a characters to the text box) if the from was opened as a result of clicking a text box on a previous form the first click on the new form is ignored. If the second form was opened as a result of clicking on a BUTTON on the first form, the second form's buttons respond correctly on first click.

Comment: You seem to not understand the problem. We have NO IDEA what framework / language / technology you're using. Your question as currently stated applies to dozens of different languages and UI frameworks therefore it has dozens of potential different answers.

Comment: @TreyHaight what technologies are you using?

Comment: My apologies!  I am using VB.Net, 2012.

Comment: @TreyHaight then your question should be TAGGED [VB.Net], and probably [winforms]

Comment: When you open your form, isn't it tied to the button click event?  Isn't there also a click event on your textbox?  These would be separate events, no?  Couldn't you specify separate functionality within each event?

Comment: Is there a way to upload a PDF that displays what I am working on?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your issue is one of focus.  When you trigger the virtual keyboard form to open because of the textbox click, you are somehow immediately returning focus to the caller, and not to the newly opened form.  Therefore, you might need something as simple as:

```
myForm.Focus()
```

...at the end of the code that is opening the form.

I say this because the first click is "ignored", as you say.  I would guess that it's actually consuming that first click as a focus event, and then you get the clicks you want registered as you want after that.

Comment: I tried the focus thought but no luck. It is curious why when I click a label there are problems with first click on the new form but when I click a button, there is no problem on the new form.